Nodemailer to send a letter with a proxy
I can't send an e-mail via Nodemailer with authenticated proxy. Error: Socks5 proxy rejected connection - ConnectionRefused. If I don't use proxy, everything works. Code (of course my data is valid):
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true для порта 465, false для других портов
    auth: {
        user: 'test@gmail.com',
        pass: 'zzxxcc'
    },
    proxy: 'socks://user:pass@138.59.1.1:5555'
});

transporter.set('proxy_socks_module', require('socks'));

let mailOptions = {
  from: "test@gmail.com",
  to: "priem@gmail.com",
  subject: "theme",
  text: "hi"
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        ended = error.message;
        resolve()
    } else {
        ended = 1;
        resolve()
    }
});

Error: Socks5 proxy rejected connection - ConnectionRefused

"use this"
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: '###########',
                pass: '###########'
            }
        });

const info = await transporter.sendMail({

            from: `senderemail@gmail.com`, 
            to: `${email}`, // list of receivers
            subject: `Hello ${email}`, // Subject line
            text: `Hello ${email}`, // plain text body
            html: `<h1>Product You Buy From SampleCreate</h1><br><h2>your buy product are</h2> <p>${data}</p>
              <br> <h3>Thanks ${email} for shooping with Us</h3>`, // html body
        });


Not a hint of proxy
